# Failure to run container after building IMAGE

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to set up IMAGE docker and I have a problem when I try to run the application and I would appreciate some help.
I define the following definition in the Dockerfile in order for the container to run the application for me:

```
CMD [ "python3", "-m", "JenkinsTestRunner/MultiTestsRunner" ]
```

But when I try to run the container docker build -t autmotionqa:latest . I get the error

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named JenkinsTestRunner/MultiTestsRunner
```

When I perform DEBUG for each operation, I see that the CMD setting tries to run the application for me from the main directory that I set as `WORKDIR: Automation`
And basically the fact that the path I entered in the CMD was not captured (Automation/JenkinsTestRunner/MultiTestAutomation)

```
sudo docker build -t autmotionqa:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  75.56MB
Step 1/14 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 3bc6e9f30f51
Step 2/14 : RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y upgrade
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4be823cb5aff
Step 3/14 : RUN apt-get install -y python3.9
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cabb45f4e49a
Step 4/14 : RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d4e44db5391
Step 5/14 : RUN pip install pipenv
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9567ded70eb0
Step 6/14 : RUN useradd -rm -d /home/bob -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 bob
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 12f35e21a1a8
Step 7/14 : USER bob
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9f5082d3cb8f
Step 8/14 : WORKDIR /home/bob/Automation/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ab6631c348a
Step 9/14 : COPY Automation .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6429d1e723ab
Step 10/14 : RUN pwd && ls -l
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 707ccb98384d
Step 11/14 : RUN pipenv install --system
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 76b87b2b13bf
Step 12/14 : RUN cd JenkinsTestRunner/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c7d68f093d03
Step 13/14 : RUN pwd && ls -l
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c63d2085772e
Step 14/14 : CMD [ "python3", "-m", "JenkinsTestRunner/MultiTestsRunner" ]
 ---> Running in 437f8ec53eac
Removing intermediate container 437f8ec53eac
 ---> 1ad52d9add10
Successfully built 1ad52d9add10
Successfully tagged autmotionqa:latest
####
 sudo docker run autmotionqa:latest
/usr/bin/python3: No module named JenkinsTestRunner/MultiTestsRunner
```

Comment: The contents of the `Dockerfile` are probably more interesting than the `docker build` output.  Is there a line that `COPY`s code into the `./JenkinsTestRunner` directory?  `RUN cd ...` has no effect on later commands (though if it's successful, the directory does exist at least).

Comment: `docker run --rm autmotionqa ls ./JenkinsTestRunner` could be an interesting thing to check.